# C# .NET 4.5 and EF 5 update navigation property (foreign key)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, unity-container

I can't update navigation property
I have two entities: User

```
public class User : Entity
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public int? AddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

And Address

```
public class Address : Entity
{
    public string AddressName { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

}
```

When i am trying to do following:

```
address.User = user;
```

address userId updates succesfully, and in commit method, entity state is Modified.
But users AddressId won't update.

Here is my context

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<Address>  Addresses { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                    .HasOptional(x=>x.Address)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(x=>x.AddressId)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

And i am using unity framework and genereic repository pattern.
I tried to set all properties to virtual but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a conception problem here, beyond your foreign key problem.
Why do you refer an `AddressId` if you have already an `Address` object in your `User` class ? It's the same thing for your `Address` class.
Maybe you should try something like this :

```
public class User : Entity
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address : Entity
{
    public string AddressName { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

But just to make it clear, Entity Framework is not a magic wizard (clause to...). With your architecture, you have to manually update BOTH foreign keys (if you want to keep your AddressId and UserId properties).

Comment: if i remover AddressId and UserId ... how ef will know how to map this navigation properties ?

Comment: In fact, EF is not using your AddressId and UserId properties... These are just for your confort in coding. EF is keeping a reference to the class instead, so when you type public virtual User User { get; set; }, EF will automaticaly assume that you're referencing the User class you previously created, and it'll do all the job for you.

Comment: Have you even try what I just suggested ? I tried this right now and it worked perfectly.

Comment: i tried. but nothing. problem, that i'm using not pure ef.. i am using unity framework for IoC and DI. And plz if you can send ur test project to me by email!

Comment: I wasn't testing with Unity. Maybe you should consider reading this article : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/547016/Code-First-Approach-using-Entity-Framework-4-1-Inv